# Azure Blob Storage (Development Connection Issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have started implementing the Azure Blob storage into my application and when using the development connection string ("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;") it unfortunately fails when trying to create the container here:

The exception is:
*Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException was unhandled by user code
InnerException: 
       Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
       Source=System.Private.CoreLib
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2147012867
            Message=A connection with the server could not be established
            Source=System.Private.CoreLib
       ....*

My code:

```
public async void UploadBlob(IFormFile file, string containerReference, string blobReference)
    {
        var container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerReference);
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobReference);

        using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why I would not be able to connect?

Thanks, Nik

Comment: Did you start up the local storage emulator?

Comment: How would I start it? I can see the AzureStorageEmulatorDb45 in the SQL Server Object explorer in VS, but have not started anything..

Answer (score 2):

I had to start the local storage emulator, which I have totally overseen in the tutorial that I looked at. Thank you for your tip Kenneth!

See here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/#authenticating-requests-against-the-storage-emulator